Get all fields from model (Matters and Contacts)
I'm trying to retrieve all fields from the Matters and Contacts models. I need this to set up mappings to later use the information coming from webhook calls. I need this to retrieve directly from the models, not from the contacts or matters registered into Clio.
I even have examples of what I need:
To the Matters, the call should return this:
[
    "id",
    "etag",
    "number",
    "display_number",
    "custom_number",
    "description",
    "status",
    "location",
    "client_reference",
    "billable",
    "maildrop_address",
    "billing_method",
    "open_date",
    "close_date",
    "pending_date",
    "created_at",
    "updated_at",
    "contingency_fee",
    "custom_rate",
    "client.id",
    "client.etag",
    "client.name",
    "client.first_name",
    "client.middle_name",
    "client.last_name",
    "client.type",
    "client.created_at",
    "client.updated_at",
    "client.prefix",
    "client.title",
    "client.initials",
    "client.clio_connect_email",
    "client.primary_email_address",
    "client.primary_phone_number",
    "client.is_client",
    "client.ledes_client_id",
    "client.addresses.0.street",
    "client.addresses.0.city",
    "client.addresses.0.province",
    "client.addresses.0.postal_code",
    "client.addresses.0.country",
    "client.addresses.0.name",
    "client.custom_field_values.0.id",
    "client.custom_field_values.0.value",
    "client.email_addresses.0.address",
    "client.email_addresses.0.name",
    "client.phone_numbers.0.number",
    "client.phone_numbers.0.name",
    "client.web_sites.0.address",
    "client.web_sites.0.name",
    "client.account_balances.0.id",
    "client.account_balances.0.balance",
    "client.account_balances.0.type",
    "client.account_balances.0.name",
    "client.primary_work_address.0.street",
    "client.primary_work_address.0.city",
    "client.primary_work_address.0.province",
    "client.primary_work_address.0.postal_code",
    "client.primary_work_address.0.country",
    "client.primary_work_address.0.name",
    "client.primary_address.0.street",
    "client.primary_address.0.city",
    "client.primary_address.0.province",
    "client.primary_address.0.postal_code",
    "client.primary_address.0.country",
    "client.primary_address.0.name",
    "client.company.0.name",
    "client.company.0.first_name",
    "client.company.0.middle_name",
    "client.company.0.last_name",
    "client.company.0.type",
    "client.company.0.prefix",
    "client.company.0.title",
    "client.company.0.initials",
    "client.company.0.primary_email_address",
    "client.company.0.primary_phone_number",
    "client.avatar.0.url",
    "client.primary_web_site.0.address",
    "client.primary_web_site.0.name",
    "matter_budget.id",
    "matter_budget.budget",
    "matter_budget.include_expenses",
    "originating_attorney.account_owner",
    "originating_attorney.email",
    "originating_attorney.first_name",
    "originating_attorney.id",
    "originating_attorney.initials",
    "originating_attorney.last_name",
    "originating_attorney.name",
    "originating_attorney.phone_number",
    "originating_attorney.rate",
    "responsible_attorney.account_owner",
    "responsible_attorney.email",
    "responsible_attorney.first_name",
    "responsible_attorney.id",
    "responsible_attorney.initials",
    "responsible_attorney.last_name",
    "responsible_attorney.name",
    "responsible_attorney.phone_number",
    "responsible_attorney.rate",
    "custom_field_values.id",
    "custom_field_values.value"
]

To the Contacts, the call should return this:
[
    "id",
    "etag",
    "name",
    "first_name",
    "middle_name",
    "last_name",
    "type",
    "created_at",
    "updated_at",
    "prefix",
    "title",
    "initials",
    "clio_connect_email",
    "primary_email_address",
    "primary_phone_number",
    "is_client",
    "ledes_client_id",
    "addresses.street",
    "addresses.city",
    "addresses.province",
    "addresses.postal_code",
    "addresses.country",
    "addresses.name",
    "custom_field_values.id",
    "custom_field_values.value",
    "email_addresses.address",
    "email_addresses.name",
    "phone_numbers.number",
    "phone_numbers.name",
    "web_sites.address",
    "web_sites.name",
    "account_balances.id",
    "account_balances.balance",
    "account_balances.type",
    "account_balances.name",
    "primary_work_address.street",
    "primary_work_address.city",
    "primary_work_address.province",
    "primary_work_address.postal_code",
    "primary_work_address.country",
    "primary_work_address.name",
    "primary_address.street",
    "primary_address.city",
    "primary_address.province",
    "primary_address.postal_code",
    "primary_address.country",
    "primary_address.name",
    "company.name",
    "company.first_name",
    "company.middle_name",
    "company.last_name",
    "company.type",
    "company.prefix",
    "company.title",
    "company.initials",
    "company.primary_email_address",
    "company.primary_phone_number",
    "avatar.url",
    "primary_web_site.address",
    "primary_web_site.name"
]

Have any of you ever needed to do something similar?
Thanks
The documentation doesn't mention anything about this.
